# Referencing asset in javascript

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

The [Ember CLI guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/#asset-compilation) describes how assets can be referenced in the templates and the CSS - but what is the proper way of referencing an asset (say an image) from my javascript code?

Specifically I am concerned about the asset path getting fingerprinted correctly when building assets for production. It seems like ember-cli is using [broccoli-asset-rev](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev) for this, but according to its [documentation](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev), only `<script>` tags in the HTML and `url()` in CSS will be fingerprinted. Is there any way (probably through another broccoli plugin) to get asset paths in the .js files fingerprinted, too?

Comment: Out of curiosity what is your use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: In this case I am using a Google Maps API plugin that gets passed an image path to display on the map. I may be able to work around it via CSS, but I am also just generally curious on how this would work.

Comment: Wouldn't you be passing this path value into the component in your template? Or are you saying this value would be different, and would have to be passed in programmatically?

Comment: Yes, programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. This works out of the box as expected - it turned out that my asset (image) was not in the right location, so  occurrences of it's path in the JS files never got replaced with the fingerprinted version.

Answer (score 3):

I placed an image called `car.jpeg` under `public/assets/images` and then was able to reference it in my `application.js` route file as `assets/images/car.jpeg`

[image]

Works great

[image]

**UPDATE**

One picture is worth a thousand words... :)

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works in development, but I don't think the asset path will get fingerprinted correctly when compiling - will it?

Comment: Only one way to find out :)

Comment: Yes, but what if the image is also fingerprinted? In that case the asset path in the JavaScript file wouldn't update

Comment: True. To that point, it's kinda interesting how pretty much everything else is fingetprinted... :)

Comment: I think that has to do with the default settings of ember-cli. If you explicitly include the image files in the Brocfile (as per the documentation of broccoli-asset-rev), the fingerprinting works as expected.